# DPDK-Pktgen from DPDK NIC to directly connected non-DPDK NIC (different servers) not working

Tags: dpdk

I've been playing around with DPDK and trying to create the following scenario.
I have 2 identical servers with 2 different NICs each. The goal is from server1 to send packets in different rates (up to the link maximum using DPDK), and capture the packets on the other side where an app will be running.

On server1 one NIC (Netronome) is taken by DPDK, but on server 2 it's not. The NICs are directly connected with fiber.
On server1 I run
`./dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci 0000:05:00.0`
and then pktgen. It appears to be working (packets are being reported as sent by pktgen). However on the other side (server2), the inteface goes down the moment I devbind. From:

```
Settings for enp6s0np1:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: None
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: None
    Speed: 40000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: Direct Attach Copper
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Link detected: yes
```

it goes to:

```
ethtool enp6s0np1
Settings for enp6s0np1:
    Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: None
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: None
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: Other
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Link detected: no
```

It thinks that there is no physical connection between the two NICs and obviously this is not the case.

```
 enp6s0np1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:4d:13:30:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The pktgen output:

```
\ Ports 0-1 of 2   <Main Page>  Copyright(c) <2010-2021>, Intel Corporation
  Flags:Port        : P------Sngl       :0
Link State          :           <--Down-->     ---Total Rate---
Pkts/s Rx           :                    0                    0
       Tx           :               14,976               14,976
MBits/s Rx/Tx       :                 0/10                 0/10
Pkts/s Rx Max       :                    0                    0
       Tx Max       :               15,104               15,104
Broadcast           :                    0
Multicast           :                    0
Sizes 64            :                    0
      65-127        :                    0
      128-255       :                    0
      256-511       :                    0
      512-1023      :                    0
      1024-1518     :                    0
Runts/Jumbos        :                  0/0
ARP/ICMP Pkts       :                  0/0
Errors Rx/Tx        :                  0/0
Total Rx Pkts       :                    0
      Tx Pkts       :            2,579,072
      Rx/Tx MBs     :              0/1,733
TCP Flags           :               .A....
TCP Seq/Ack         :  305419896/305419920
Pattern Type        :              abcd...
Tx Count/% Rate     :        Forever /0.1%
Pkt Size/Tx Burst   :            64 /  128
TTL/Port Src/Dest   :       10/ 1234/ 8000
Pkt Type:VLAN ID    :      IPv4 / UDP:0001
802.1p CoS/DSCP/IPP :            0/  0/  0
VxLAN Flg/Grp/vid   :     0000/    0/    0
IP  Destination     :          192.168.0.2
    Source          :          192.168.0.1
MAC Destination     :    00:15:4d:13:30:5c
    Source          :    00:15:4d:13:30:81
PCI Vendor/Addr     :    19ee:4000/05:00.0
```

when I try to capture with `tcpdump -i enp6s0np1`, it doesn't record anything. Are those issues related and if yes, is there any workaround? Shouldn't some packets be captured by tcpdump on server2?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm this got resolved. Apparently the NIC has two ports and only one was connected. Therefore the issue was the `Link State down` below.

```
 Ports 0-1 of 2   <Main Page>  Copyright(c) <2010-2021>, Intel Corporation
  Flags:Port        : P------Sngl       :0
Link State          :           <--Down-->
```

To resolve it I had to use port 1 instead of port 0